# What is the difference between an efs provisioner and efs csi driver?

Tags: amazon-web-services, storage, amazon-eks, provisioning, amazon-efs

While I am trying to implement EFS volumes in my EKS cluster, as I am checking in forums, I could see 2 solutions

1. Using efs provisioner
2. Using efs CSI driver

What is the actual difference between these two?

I am running Jenkins in AWS EKS with EBS currently. Now I wish to change the storage solution from EBS to EFS.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean [this](https://github.com/kubernetes-retired/external-storage/tree/master/aws/efs) EFS provisioner, that was a very early on project that has since been retired. I strongly recommend using the [EFS CSI driver](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/efs-csi.html) now. Note that up until earlier this year the CSI driver did not have a way to do dynamic provisioning (which the EFS provisioner had) but we have eventually released [dynamic provisioning](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/introducing-efs-csi-dynamic-provisioning/) support.

Comment: thanks for commenting, efs provisioner I mean is this one "https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/isotoma/efs-provisioner"

Comment: Yeah, that chart points to https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage/tree/master/aws/efs which in turns redirect to the retired repo I linked above (https://github.com/kubernetes-retired/external-storage/tree/master/aws/efs). What I am missing is why that chart is still getting updates (last version is from April 2021) when the last commit on the retired repo is from 2019.